# There is no overloaded version of 'inttostr' that can be called with these arguments

Tags: pascal

I am writing a simple program that converts a decimal integer into a binary number.
I am a beginner, so there might be multiple things wrong with.

This is the function I am using:

```
function DecToBin (dec:integer): string;
var
  bin: string;
  bit:real;
begin
  write('Enter the decimal integer to be converted: ');
  readln(dec);
  bin := '';
  repeat
    bit := dec mod 2;
    bin := inttostr(bit) + bin;
    dec := dec div 2;
  until dec = 0;
result :=bin;
end;
```

The error I am getting is 
"There is no overloaded version of 'inttostr' that can be called with these arguments".

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You must declare `bit` as an integer.

Comment: The `Int` in `IntToStr` should tell you it's for `Int` (AKA Integer) values and not Real values. Real values would be floating point values, and floating point values are converted with `FloatToStr` or `FormatFloat` instead. But you have no need for a floating point value in the first place, as LURD has pointed out.